# Pandas not one hot encoding data

Tags: python, pandas

This code :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id_val' : [1.0 , 2.0, 3.0] , 'c1': [1.0 , 2.0, 3.0], 'c2': [1.0 , 2.0, 3.0], 'c3': [1.0 , 2.0, 3.0] })
df
```

generates the dataframe :

[image]

Attempting to one-hot encode this dataframe using get_dummies :

```
pd.get_dummies(df)
```

renders the same dataframe :

[image]

How do I one hot encode the dataframe using `get_dummies` ?

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to `string`s:

```
print (pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str)))
   id_val_1.0  id_val_2.0  id_val_3.0  c1_1.0  c1_2.0  c1_3.0  c2_1.0  c2_2.0  \
0           1           0           0       1       0       0       1       0   
1           0           1           0       0       1       0       0       1   
2           0           0           1       0       0       1       0       0   

   c2_3.0  c3_1.0  c3_2.0  c3_3.0  
0       0       1       0       0  
1       0       0       1       0  
2       1       0       0       1
```

If want dummies only from `c` columns:

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df.filter(like='c').astype(str), prefix_sep='', prefix='')
         .max(axis=1, level=0))
print (df1)
   1.0  2.0  3.0
0    1    0    0
1    0    1    0
2    0    0    1
```